# Gradle Issue after updating to AGP 8.2.1 in flutter project (android build)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

After updating to AGP 8.2.1 gradle clean works fine, but 'gradle build' gives me errors for many of my dependencies:

### `11: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_messaging:processDebugManifest'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
> Incorrect package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/andreasr/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.7.16/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
> Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
> Recommendation: remove package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/andreasr/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.7.16/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
> `

My build script from android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Ran Android Studio AGP Update assistant and update AGP from 4.1.0 to 8.2.2 to fix issues with AGP < 8.
Added

```
afterEvaluate {
    android {
        namespace 'at.peakclub.nevo'
    }
}
```

to my build.gradle to fix namespace issues for packages not supporting it - leaded to a sucessful gradle clean.

Of course, ran flutter clean, flutter pub get/upgrade and gradle clean before - but no change